# Building boost_exception library in windows VS2015

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, boost, build

I am trying to build boost exception library but unable to do so. Here is what I have done.

```
cd <to boost dir>
bootstrap.exe 
b2.exe link=shared runtime-link=shared --with-exception
```

This generates static libraries `libboost_exception-<...>.lib` but not `boost_exception-<...>.lib` and `boost_exception-<...>.dll`.

I am using Visual Studio developer command prompt to build boost.

What I might be doing wrong?

Comment: You are not doing anything wrong, it's just that Boost.Exception [requires](https://github.com/boostorg/exception/blob/boost-1.62.0/build/Jamfile.v2) to be built with static linking (no idea why).

Answer (score 0):

Boost Exception is header-only, there is no need to build anything.

Comment: [Boost.Exception provides non-intrusive implementation of exception_ptr for 32-bit _MSC_VER==1310 and _MSC_VER==1400 which requires a separately-compiled binary.](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#header-only-libraries)